# jQuery image slider not working with jQuery show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, bxslider

I am using the bxslider (http://bxslider.com/examples/multiple-slideshows) jQuery image slider  and it seems to be acting erratically when used with a jQuery show/hide. It seems to be working fine on a desktop, but is not working on tablet. On tablet, the first slider works fine, but upon clicking through to the next div, using jQuery show/hide, the next slider is broken. Just displays the background image and then all the slides are shrunken and at the top of the slider. BUT, strangely, when you rotate the tablet, from portrait to landscape or vice versa, it works. Any help is GREATLY appreciated. The page is here: http://www.parker-gibson.com/mqm_test/hawkeye_beef.html

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Midwest Quality Meats</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="top-nav">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="hawkeye.html">Hawkeye Meats</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#">...</a></li>-->
                <!--<li><a href="#">...</a></li>-->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Meats</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="beef.html">Beef</a></li>
                <li><a href="pork.html">Pork</a></li>
                <li><a href="chicken.html">Chicken</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <a href="index.html" style="display:block; float:left; margin:0 95px 0 25px;"><img src="img/ribbon.png"></a>

        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li style="margin-right:15px;"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div> <!--end top nav-->

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="nav spacer" style="width:960px; height:80px;">
</div>

<div id="meat-wrap">

<div id="cuts-container">
    <div id="hwk-beef-nav-top">
    </div>
    <div id="cuts">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="strip_btn"><h2>New York Strip Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="tbone_btn"><h2>T-Bone Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="sirloin_btn"><h2>Top Sirloin Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="filet_btn"><h2>Sirloin Filet Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="chuck_btn"><h2>Chuck Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="beefpatty_btn"><h2>Ground Beef Patty</h2></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="animal-nav">
    <a href="pork.html"><div id="pork-nav" style="border-right:1px solid #000;"></div></a>
    <a href="chicken.html"><div id="chicken-nav"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!---------------------new york strip------------------------->
<div id="strip">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider1">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/strip1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/strip-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/strip2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">New York Strip Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end strip-->

<!---------------------t-bone------------------------->
<div id="tbone">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider2">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/tbone1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/tbone-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/tbone2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">T-Bone Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end tbone-->

<!---------------------sirloin------------------------->
<div id="sirloin">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider3">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/sirloin1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/sirloin-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/sirloin2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Top Sirloin Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end sirloin-->

<!---------------------filet------------------------->
<div id="filet">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider4">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/filet1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/filet-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/filet2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Sirloin Filet Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end filet-->

<!---------------------chuck------------------------->
<div id="chuck">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider5">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/chuck1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/chuck-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/chuck2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Chuck Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end chuck-->

<!---------------------beefpatty------------------------->
<div id="beefpatty">
<div id="cut-slider">
<ul id="slider6">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/patty1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/patty-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/patty2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Ground Beef Patty</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end beefpatty-->

</div> <!--end meat wrap-->

</div> <!--end container-->

<div id="footer"></div>

    <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider2').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider3').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider4').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider5').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider6').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
});
</script>
<!--show/hide effects-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
              $("#strip").show();
              $("#tbone, #sirloin, #filet, #chuck, #beefpatty").hide();
              $("#strip_btn").addClass('active_btn');

$("#strip_btn").click(function () {
              $("#strip").fadeIn('slow');
              $("#tbone, #sirloin, #filet, #chuck, #beefpatty").hide();
              $(this).addClass('active_btn');
              $("#tbone_btn, #sirloin_btn, #filet_btn, #chuck_btn, #beefpatty_btn").removeClass('active_btn');
              return false;
            });
$("#tbone_btn").click(function () {
              $("#tbone").fadeIn('slow');
              $("#strip, #sirloin, #filet, #chuck, #beefpatty").hide();
              $(this).addClass('active_btn');
              $("#strip_btn, #sirloin_btn, #filet_btn, #chuck_btn, #beefpatty_btn").removeClass('active_btn');
              return false;
            });
              $("#tbone_btn").click(function() {   // button that sets the DIV visible
              $("#slider2").show();     // DIV that contain SLIDER
              mySlider.reloadShow();        // Reloads the slideshow (bxSlider API function)
            });
$("#sirloin_btn").click(function () {
              $("#sirloin").fadeIn('slow');
              $("#strip, #tbone, #filet, #chuck, #beefpatty").hide();
              $(this).addClass('active_btn');
              $("#strip_btn, #tbone_btn, #filet_btn, #chuck_btn, #beefpatty_btn").removeClass('active_btn');
              return false;
            });
              $("#sirloin_btn").click(function() {   // button that sets the DIV visible
              $("#slider3").show();     // DIV that contain SLIDER
              mySlider.reloadShow();        // Reloads the slideshow (bxSlider API function)
            });
$("#filet_btn").click(function () {
              $("#filet").fadeIn('slow');
              $("#strip, #tbone, #sirloin, #chuck, #beefpatty").hide();
              $(this).addClass('active_btn');
              $("#strip_btn, #tbone_btn, #sirloin_btn, #chuck_btn, #beefpatty_btn").removeClass('active_btn');
              return false;
            });
              $("#filet_btn").click(function() {   // button that sets the DIV visible
              $("#slider4").show();     // DIV that contain SLIDER
              mySlider.reloadShow();        // Reloads the slideshow (bxSlider API function)
            });
$("#chuck_btn").click(function () {
              $("#chuck").fadeIn('slow');
              $("#strip, #tbone, #sirloin, #filet, #beefpatty").hide();
              $(this).addClass('active_btn');
              $("#strip_btn, #tbone_btn, #sirloin_btn, #filet_btn, #beefpatty_btn").removeClass('active_btn');
              return false;
            });
              $("#chuck_btn").click(function() {   // button that sets the DIV visible
              $("#slider5").show();     // DIV that contain SLIDER
              mySlider.reloadShow();        // Reloads the slideshow (bxSlider API function)
            });
$("#beefpatty_btn").click(function () {
              $("#beefpatty").fadeIn('slow');
              $("#strip, #tbone, #sirloin, #filet, #chuck").hide();
              $(this).addClass('active_btn');
              $("#strip_btn, #tbone_btn, #sirloin_btn, #filet_btn, #chuck_btn").removeClass('active_btn');
              return false;
            });
              $("#beefpatty_btn").click(function() {   // button that sets the DIV visible
              $("#slider6").show();     // DIV that contain SLIDER
              mySlider.reloadShow();        // Reloads the slideshow (bxSlider API function)
            });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see I reloaded the slideshow just after the DIV (that contain the slider) was showed and it worked perfectly.

```
<script>

var mySlider;

$(function() {

    mySlider = $('#slider').bxSlider({
            easing: 'easeInCubic',
            displaySlideQty: 3,
            moveSlideQty: 1,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            hideControlOnEnd: true
    });

    $("#processSignUp").click(function() {   // button that sets the DIV visible
        $("#trainings-slide").show();     // DIV that contain SLIDER
        mySlider.reloadShow();        // Reloads the slideshow (bxSlider API function)
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Would you be able to tell me where to put that in my code? I'm not good at all with jQuery

Comment: you have initialized all sliders in a single line,you have to initialise seperately and cal whenever you show like mySlider.reloadShow();

Comment: I edited the javascript at the bottom of my code. I initialized all sliders separately. as far as the, mySlider.reloadShow(); i don't really know what you mean. where I have it now is not working. See code?